# Repeating Multiple Images As Background in different Styles

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, background-image

In My Present project End User will Select Any Image from his computer, then we should display that image in below formats.

[image: Basic Format]
[image: Half Drop Format]
[image: Half-Brik Format]
[image: Center Format]
[image: Mirror Format]

The Formats Above Are **Normal Repeat**, **Half- Drop**, **Half-Brick**, **Center**, **Mirror** respectively

So for that i started working on CSS Background image tricks. But i didnt Got 100% solution with that.

### **What I have done**

1. Taken a Division of **400px width** and **400px height**
2. Repeated a image using `Background-position:` and `Background-repeat:` properties
3. Repeated the image in `repeat-x` and `repeat-y` respective to the formats.
4. Repeated the image in such a way to fit with `400px height` and `400px width`
5. As per my code if we want to repeat the image in **4 rows** then we should write **4 background property lines**

Please go through the [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sree1254/ts2Bn/) for better understanding.

### **What I Want Is**

1. Solution can be in **CSS** or **Jquery**
2. If it There is a solution in CSS:  The background repetition should be done **automatically** even if am increasing the height of the division.
3. I am not getting any idea to to do the repetition of image in **Mirror Format** (as last image mentioned above).

Please give your suggestions to make it perfect.

**Note : Please Forgive me for my poor explanation. Please go through the Js Fiddle File (You will understand what i want).**

Comment: Please Let Me know : Is It Possible in Css...? If not then please share a tutorial which you found it may help me.

Comment: Is this driven dynamically from a database? I.E can you have a repeating lop with html in it.

Comment: Easily doable, even if you want the image variants to be handled user-side. Look into the CSS3 transform property.

Comment: I think you'd have to have the images as a repeating elements and use CSS3 to flip them for the mirror mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JavaScript and the canvas element to modify the background image.

For the **half-drop** mode create a canvas element with twice the width of the image and draw the image on the canvas like this:

```
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
context.drawImage(image, width, height / -2, width, height);
context.drawImage(image, width, height / 2, width, height);
```

For the **mirror** mode use this:

```
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
context.save();
context.scale(-1, 1);
context.drawImage(image, -width * 2, 0, width, height);
context.scale(1, -1);
context.drawImage(image, -width * 2, -height * 2, width, height);
context.scale(-1, 1);
context.drawImage(image, 0, -height * 2, width, height);
context.restore();
```

To set the canvas element as background image use `canvas.toDataURL()`:

```
element.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + canvas.toDataURL('image/png') + '")';
```

Look at this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdL47/3/) for a full working example.

More information about the canvas element: [Tutorial on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial)

Comment: Thanks a lot.....!!! Can you please give me any reference link to know breifly about canvas..?

Comment: I am new for canvas concept. I got exact solution what i want. But i want to know what is going on in each line of the code. Can you please explain me when you are free.?

Comment: And How you converted the image into encoding code..?

Comment: @Sreeram I added a tutorial link about canvas and added some comments to the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to answer this question, but if it was me, I'd make it a repeating element. I'm not sure what you're using for your server technology (PHP or ASP) but I would have some if statements setup.

If its in the mirror mode:

```
.mirrorLeft {
        width:50%;
        position:aboslute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

.mirrorRight {
        width:50%;
        position:aboslute;
        right:0;
        top:0;
        min-height:100%;
        background-repeat:repeat-y;
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}

<div class="background">
    <div class="mirrorLeft"></div>
    <div class="mirrorRight"></div>
</div>
```

Obviously I left our the background image source, I'm just giving an example of how to setup the positioning.